# How to customize cell backgrounds

Tags: ios, swift

Currently working on a Swift application, and I have built a slide out navigation menu using an API at https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController. I'm trying to change the background image of each cell from the blank and boring white color into an image I choose of my own.

I have checked many resources from Stack Overflow `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]` which I inserted at the beginning of a case statement seems to produce the error of: **Expected Expression From String Literal.** Where would I insert a statement for background image and what would it be?

```
class LeftSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var menuItems:[String] = ["Daily Quote","Passion", "Failure","Dream","Grind","Hang on","Haters","Wisdom","Karma"];


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

        mycell.menuItemLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
        return mycell;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        switch(indexPath.row){

        case 0:

            var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

            var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController

            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

 break;
        case 1:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]

            var aboutViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PassionViewController") as! PassionViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

 break;

        case 2:

            var aboutViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FailureViewController") as! FailureViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
break;
        case 3:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DreamViewController")
            as! DreamViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break;

        case 4:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GrindViewController")
                as! GrindViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
break;
        case 5:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HangViewController")
                as! HangViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
break;

        case 6:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HaterViewController")
                as! HaterViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
break;
        case 7:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WisdomViewController")
                as! WisdomViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
break;
        case 8:

            var aboutViewController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KarmaViewController")
                as! KarmaViewController

            var aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

            var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController
            appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

        default:

            println("\(menuItems[indexPath.row]) is selected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to make sure you set the cell `backgroundColor` to clear and also the cell `contentView.backgroundColor` to clear. Otherwise you will not see the image. To set the image create a UIView with the background color from image set and assign that to cell.backgroundView. You can set the cells backgroundColor, but it will only show as long as the `contentView` background is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically also by creating a custom class for tableview cell. for example inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath call the custom class

```
var imageArray = ["pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png"]
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var mycell = MyCustomClass(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50), row: indexPath.row, imageArray: imageArray)
    mycell.menuItemLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    return mycell;
}

class MyCustomClass: UITableViewCell {
    var menuItemLabel: UILabel!
    init(frame: CGRect, row: Int, imageArray: Array<String>) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

       //declare a image array that has the name of the image to be included
       var image = imageArray[row]

        backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "\(image)")!)
        menuItemLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, 50))
        addSubview(menuItemLabel)
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Background image seems to overlap the text... Can't see text... and also it does not customize one but all at the same time...

Comment: so what do you want to achieve? have different image for each cell?

Comment: You're solution looks legitimate, but I can't seem to make an image array to work with this code, can you provide me with a possible solution?

Comment: @HenryLi I have edited the code. pls note the image array should be defined in the class where the tableview delegate functions are written.

Comment: string not convertible to type image, i've tried something else like array:UIImage[] = [] but also doesnt work

Comment: var mycell = MyCustomClass(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 50), row: indexPath.row, imageArray: imageArray) generating error

Comment: I dont know..wasn't me.
The array index is out of range, because you might be calling it for more than 3 times in number of rows. So what u should do is that the number of images in the array should be equal to the number of rows you return in the numberOfRows delegate function

Comment: Thanks! Trying to implement one sec.

Comment: Sweet finally working! Marked your question as correct, but if you have the time can you tell me why when it is clicked the image turns gray. I don't know if you can have it still the same image. If you can't then it's cool! Thanks Alot, appreciate it.Can't upvote since I just had 15 rep but now 13 ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84429/discussion-between-fooo-and-henry-li).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following code :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)
```

Comment: Where I insert this statement, whenever I tap on that cell the top (which is a catergories label I added)'s background changes, it does something but not the right thing

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set view background, then you have to set for each cell a transparent background color color:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.background = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundImage")!)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    mycell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    mycell.menuItemLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    return mycell;
}
```

## update

With a custom cell created on a xib (eg. "MyCustomTableViewCell.xib"), you have to do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCellIdentifier")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
   ...
}
```

And you have to set MyCustomTableViewCellIdentifier name on xib:

[image]

Comment: Error: can't invoke clear color with no arguments and UIView has no member named background error

Comment: sorry, I have put two useless brachets: UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: works only on the one prototype cell i made not the cells i programatically made, how do you make it target the other cells?